# Implications of disregarding Samuel's warnings

Tags: historical-interpretation, 1-samuel

Samuel 8:10-18 (KJV):

> And Samuel told all the words of the Lord unto the people that asked
> of him a king.
>
> And he said, This will be the manner of the king that shall reign over
> you: He will take your sons, and appoint them for himself, for his
> chariots, and to be his horsemen; and some shall run before his
> chariots.
>
> And he will appoint him captains over thousands, and captains over
> fifties; and will set them to ear his ground, and to reap his harvest,
> and to make his instruments of war, and instruments of his chariots.
>
> And he will take your daughters to be confectionaries, and to be
> cooks, and to be bakers.
>
> And he will take your fields, and your vineyards, and your oliveyards,
> even the best of them, and give them to his servants.
>
> And he will take the tenth of your seed, and of your vineyards, and
> give to his officers, and to his servants.
>
> And he will take your menservants, and your maidservants, and your
> goodliest young men, and your asses, and put them to his work.
>
> He will take the tenth of your sheep: and ye shall be his servants.
>
> And ye shall cry out in that day because of your king which ye shall
> have chosen you; and the Lord will not hear you in that day.

Yet he is countered with occasions when a strong leader is justified:

> Nevertheless the people refused to obey the voice of Samuel; and they
> said, Nay; but we will have a king over us;
>
> That we also may be like all the nations; and that our king may judge
> us, and go out before us, and fight our battles.

### Question

Would it be accurate to interpret this as scriptural support for authoritarianism superseding egalitarianism?

**Note:** Trying to avoid the term 'democracy' since it's a bit of an anachronism. Still, I think one's inner struggle for one's place in the order of society is universal and needs only common sense to frame the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked,

"Would it be accurate to interpret this as scriptural support for authoritarianism superseding egalitarianism?"

The answer to that is "no". The larger context of the chapter indicates that the real issue was the people of Israel rejecting their theocracy in favor of a monarchy.

Samuel appointed his two sons to be judges, but they were found wanting, and the people of Israel knew it:

1 Samuel 8:1-5a ([ESV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=1%20Samuel%208&version=ESV)),

> 1 When Samuel became old, he made his sons judges over Israel. 2 The
> name of his firstborn son was Joel, and the name of his second,
> Abijah; they were judges in Beersheba. 3 Yet his sons did not walk in
> his ways but turned aside after gain. They took bribes and perverted
> justice.
>
> 4 Then all the elders of Israel gathered together and came to Samuel
> at Ramah 5 and said to him, “Behold, you are old and your sons do not
> walk in your ways...

And because of this, the people asked Samuel to appoint for them a king:

> ...Now appoint for us a king to judge us like all the nations.”

Samuel was unhappy with such a request and made his complaint known to YHVH (See 1 Samuel 8:6).

The next verse is key:

> 7 And the Lord said to Samuel, “Obey the voice of the people in all
> that they say to you, for they have not rejected you, but they have
> rejected me from being king over them..."

The people preferred a despot over a Savior. Notice what it was the people wanted. They wanted a king to judge them and to fight their battles for them.

Yet, their ancestor Abraham said of YHVH that He was the "[Judge of All the Earth](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Genesis%2018%3A25&version=ESV)" (Genesis 18:25). Israel's God was to be their judge, yet they rejected Him.

And, many years later after Abraham, their national leader Moses, said of YHVH:

> The Lord is a man of war;
> the Lord is his name ([Exodus 15:3](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2015%3A3&version=ESV))

Indeed, at the Sea of Reeds, Moses told the people of Israel to stay silent and trust that YHVH would fight for them (See [Exodus 14:14](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Exodus%2014%3A14&version=ESV)).

Other similar verses abound. The point being, the people of Israel no longer trusted in YHVH to be for them what He had been for them, in the past. They no longer trusted in His protection and provision. They believed Him incapable of being their Sovereign.

So, I recommend looking at this passage not as a Scriptural support for authoritarianism superseding egalitarianism, but rather, a Scriptural denunciation for divine theocracy being superseded by despotic monarchy.

Comment: Excellent insight, mosaic approach from other passages very helpful too. Thanks